# How to trim every nth line?

Tags: bash, awk, cut, fastq

i would like to cut off the first 9 characters of each 4th line. I could use `cut -c 9`, but i don't know how to select only every 4th line, without loosing the remaining lines.

Input:

```
@V300059044L3C001R0010004402
AAGTAGATATCATGGAGCCG
+
FFFGFGGFGFGFFGFFGFFGGGGGFFFGG
@V300059044L3C001R0010009240
AAAGGGAGGGAGAATAATGG
+
GFFGFEGFGFGEFDFGGEFFGGEDEGEGF
```

Output:

```
@V300059044L3C001R0010004402
AAGTAGATATCATGGAGCCG
+
FGFFGFFGFFGGGGGFFFGG
@V300059044L3C001R0010009240
AAAGGGAGGGAGAATAATGG
+
FGEFDFGGEFFGGEDEGEGF
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk 'FNR%4==0{print substr($0,10);next} 1' Input_file
```

OR as per @tripleee's suggestion(in comments) try:

```
awk '!(FNR%4) { $0 = substr($0, 10) }1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                   ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR%4==0{               ##Checking condition if this line number is fully divided by 4(every 4th line).
  print substr($0,10)   ##Printing line from 10th character here.
  next                  ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
1                       ##1 will print current Line.
' Input_file            ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Maybe even refactor down to `awk '!(FNR%4) { $0 = substr($0, 10) }1'`

Comment: Worked perfectly to resolve the first issue, thanks!!!

Comment: @gnikixam, I think your cut off 9 characters on every 4th line + performance issue both should be addressed by this one IMHO.

Comment: Yeah that's right. But second aim is, to remove additionally XY characters at the end of this line. For example: line 4 the last 3 characters, line 8 the last 5 characters and so on. This is very time consuming

Comment: @gnikixam, I really thought both are same requirement only :) Do lines where you want to remove characters at last have any specific sequence or logic in their line number? Kindly do let me know.

Comment: I use `sed 's/AAAAAAAAA.*//'`to remove A-tails (analog for Gs, Ts, and Cs). Then i would compare the untrimmed seq and the trimmed to count the difference and would like to trim this amount of characters at the end of the QS row (4th).

Comment: @gnikixam, IMHO this looks 2 questions(kind of different questions) joined into one. IMHO I would like to request you to please open a new question for this one with clear details and you could keep only 1st question here, so that no one gets confuse. Honestly it was not clear(your 2nd question) so its better not to confuse current/future readers and open a new question(with your already done efforts, already shown here) for better understanding, cheers, thank you

Answer (score 2):

GNU sed can choose every 4th line with `4~4`, e.g.:

```
sed -E '4~4s/.{9}//'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The command removed all characters except 9, but it's ok. RavinderSingh13 command worked very well!

Comment: should be `sed -E '4~4s/.{9}//'` to delete first 9 characters

Comment: @gnikixam: That is what you asked for ... I suggest reading and creating an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Sundeep: indeed, I had it the wrong way around